# What is this.parentElement?

Tags: javascript

```
pg.myfunc = function(){
    var i = 1, j = 2;
    this.selected = 1;
    xx.newObject = this.parentElement;

...
```

What is `xx.newObject = this.parentElement;` doing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the same as `this.parentNode`: it gives you the node that contains `this` as a childNode. `this` will be `pg`, presumably an Element of some kind; `this.parentNode` will be the Element that contains it, or the `document` object if `pg` is the root element.

`parentElement` is a non-standard [IE extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534327%28VS.85%29.aspx). Since IE also supports the standard property `parentNode`, `parentElement` should never be used.

Alternatively, maybe it's just an arbitrary object with a property called `parentElement`, in which case it could be anything at all. There's no real way to tell from that code, but it would be unusual to be setting arbitrary properties like `myfunc` on an Element node.

Answer (score 6):

It saves a reference to the parent element of `this`. So for example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span id="child">
  </span>
</div>
```

In this case, if `this` corresponds to the `child` span, `parentElement` would correspond to the `parent` div.

That said, you should always use `parentNode` instead of `parentElement`, as `parentElement` is proprietary and (I believe) only works with IE. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534327(VS.85).aspx):

> There is no public standard that applies to this property.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know without some context.  We don't what xx is, nor do we know for sure what the "this" object is. parentElement MAY be a property to pg, but then again this function may be called in a different way, for instance if somewhere it is assigned as an onclick function:

someElement.onclick = pg.myfunc;

In which case it would be a property of someElement.

As others have said, if "this" is a DOM element, you should be using parentNode not parentElement, since the latter is non-standard.