# Difference between DOM parentNode and parentElement

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Can somebody explain in simple terms, what is the difference between classical DOM [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and newly introduced in Firefox 9 [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899196/what-is-this-parentelement

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685798

Comment: [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_parentnode.asp) seems to be DOM standard, so it is safer always use it instead of parentElement.

Comment: @TMS w3school is not an authority: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé - Have a new look on w3fools. They now say that the errors/omissions they listed have been corrected.

Comment: There's a lot of hate here directed toward `parentNode`. While `parentNode` might itself be a bit useless, remember that Nodes *are*, indeed, useful - they represent non-element parts of the DOM - comments, actual text, CDATA text, etc. ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979172/114558))

Answer (score 695, accepted):

`parentElement` is new to Firefox 9 and to DOM4, but it has been present in all other major browsers for ages.

In most cases, it is the same as `parentNode`. The only difference comes when a node's `parentNode` is not an element. If so, `parentElement` is `null`.

As an example:

```
document.body.parentNode; // the <html> element
document.body.parentElement; // the <html> element

document.documentElement.parentNode; // the document node
document.documentElement.parentElement; // null

(document.documentElement.parentNode === document);  // true
(document.documentElement.parentElement === document);  // false
```

Since the `<html>` element (`document.documentElement`) doesn't have a parent that is an element, `parentElement` is `null`. (There are other, more unlikely, cases where `parentElement` could be `null`, but you'll probably never come across them.)

Comment: In other words, it's completely pointless 99.999999999999% of the time. Whose idea was it?

Comment: The original [`parentElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534327(v=vs.85).aspx) was a proprietary IE thing; I believe other browsers at the time (e.g., Netscape) supported `parentNode` but not `parentElement`. (Obviously, given I've mentioned Netscape, I'm talking about way back to IE5 and earlier...)

Comment: @lonesomeday you forgot `documentfragment.firstChild.parentElement === null`

Comment: @Raynos That was actually the precise circumstance I had in mind with the last sentence of my answer...

Comment: I thought you were thinking of something obscure like you have a handle on a node whose parent is a ProcessingInstruction :D

Comment: As I have just discovered, on an SVG element (like a `circle` inside a `g`), in IE, `parentElement` will be undefined, and `parentNode` will be what you're looking for.  :(

Comment: @JasonWalton I have just discovered this as well and had a quick google to see if I can find a reason. I can't find a reason, but good to know I am not alone....

Comment: parentElement === null is very useful

Answer (score 124):

In Internet Explorer, `parentElement` is undefined for SVG elements, whereas `parentNode` is defined.

Comment: honestly I think this is more of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Probably, but it's the reason I banged my head against the table for an hour or more until I figured it out. I suspect many others come to this page after a similar head-banging.

Comment: @speedplane Glad this is an answer as this makes no logical sense and had me stumped for a good while...

Comment: It also undefined for comment nodes. In Chrome I was happily getting the parent of a comment, but it was undefined in IE.

Comment: I could not find a source for that. `parentElement` not being implemented for `Node` is well know (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement#Browser_compatibility) but for `SVGElement`? I could also not reproduce this with `document.createElement('svg').parentElement` in IE 11.737.17763.0. Was this maybe fixed in the meantime?

Answer (score 31):

Use `.parentElement` and you can't go wrong as long as you aren't using document fragments.

If you use document fragments, then you need `.parentNode`:

```
let div = document.createDocumentFragment().appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.parentElement // null
div.parentNode // document fragment
```

Also:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('t').content.firstChild
console.log(div.parentElement)  // null
console.log(div.parentNode)     // document fragment
```

```html
<template id="t"><div></div></template>
```

---

Apparently the `<html>`'s `.parentNode` links to the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). This should be considered a decision phail as documents aren't nodes since nodes **are defined** to be containable by documents and documents can't be contained by documents.

Answer (score 12):

Just like with [nextSibling and nextElementSibling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226603/619616), just remember that, properties with "element" in their name always returns `Element` or `null`. Properties without can return any other kind of node.

```js
console.log(document.body.parentElement, "is body's parent element");//<html>
console.log(document.body.parentNode, "is body's parent node");      //<html>

var html = document.body.parentElement;
console.log(html.parentElement, "is html's parent element");         //null
console.log(html.parentNode, "is html's parent node");               //document
```

Comment: yeah, but unlike nextsibling text or comment nodes can't be parent.

Answer (score 3):

Browser's [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) is a tree of [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s. Node is an abstract interface, which most used implementation is [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), but it is not the only one.

Thus:

- `parentNode` will return a Node's parent Node (if it has one)
- `parentElement` will return a Node's parent only if it is an Element instance

Answer (score 0):

there is one more difference, but only in internet explorer. It occurs when you mix HTML and SVG. if the parent is the 'other' of those two, then .parentNode gives the parent, while .parentElement gives undefined.

Comment: I think it's `undefined` not `null`.