# DOM ParentElement vs ParentNode

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a piece of JS that pulls data from the immediate parent of a particular element in a page. The element and its parent are both guaranteed to have certain attributes, so the case is simple. After reading this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement) about the differences between [element].parentElement and [element].parentNode, I get the impression that either one will do the job equally well. But am I right in thinking that parentNode is the better choice? I've read elsewhere that it's older and more DOM-standard. Am I liable to break some users' browsers by a wrong choice between the two alternatives?

Comment: Well, apparently FF<9 does not support `parentElement`, while `parentNode` is really supported everywhere. So yes and yes.

Comment: While it's not an exact duplicate, it addresses only one unique point of discussion. For that reason I agree it may be better to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bergi answered this question succinctly. Compliance with DOM standards suggests that `parentNode` is the preferable term. `parentElement` is not universally supported and does not introduce enough unique functionality (see the related question for further discussion on that point) to justify its use.