# What is the difference between node.nextSibling and ChildNode.nextElementSibling?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

`<div id="div-01">Here is div-01</div>
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>`

Aren't they the same thing ?

Both returning the immediately followed node. I read a lot of articles but seems to me like the same thing, but can't figure where to use one versus other ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`nextElementSibling` always returns an element.  `nextSibling` can return any kind of node.  They are the same for your example, but different in other cases, e.g.:

```
<p><span id="span-01">Here is span-01</span>
Some text at the top level
<span id="span-02">Here is span-02</span></p>
```

In this case, `document.getElementById('span-01').nextElementSibling` is `span-02`, but `document.getElementById('span-01').nextSibling` is the text node containing "Some text at the top level" (or, as pointed out by @Manngo in the comments, the whitespace that separates that text from the element above -- it seems some browsers put whitespace between elements and non-whitespace nodes into separate nodes, while others combine it with the rest of the text).

Comment: Actually, they may not be the same in the sample. Firefox sees the line break between the two `div` elements as a text node (white space), so `.nextSibling` would return that. This is a pain, but technically acceptable.