# Whats the difference between nextElementSibling vs nextSibling

Tags: javascript

Although I seem to get strange results occasionally these seem to me to be the same so can someone describe the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between node.nextSibling and ChildNode.nextElementSibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226571/what-is-the-difference-between-node-nextsibling-and-childnode-nextelementsibling)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

'nextSibling' returns the next Node object whereas 'nextElementSibling' returns the next Element object, so probably the real question is what is the difference between a Node & an Element?

Basically an Element is specified by an HTML Tag whereas a Node is any Object in the DOM, so an Element is a Node but a Node can also include Text Nodes in the form of whitespace, comments, text characters or line breaks. For more info on Elements vs Nodes see this [Difference between Node object and Element object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object)

i.e Take the following DOM snippet

```
<div id="start"></div>
Me
<p>Hi</p>
```

Using nextSibling you would get:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('start').nextSibling); // "\nMe\n"
console.log(document.getElementById('start').nextSibling.nextSibling); // "<p>
```

Whereas using nextElementSibling you would get:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('start').nextElementSibling);// "<p>"
```

Also nextElementSibling is IE10+, being the newer method whereas nextSibling has full browser support

Comment: Whitespace **is** text.

Comment: There's a little more to it than that. Nodes have a type stored as a [*nodeType*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-111237558) property. Elements have a *nodeType* of *1*, there are 11 others (see [*MDN Node.nodeType*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)). And the DOM applies to documents other than HTML.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense, so nextElementSibling seems to be the best option for me as I'm building for >IE10

Answer (score 2):

`nextSibling` will return the next node in the DOM, most probably in current web page scenarios, it is a whitespace but `nextElementSibling` will return only the next element ignoring all the nodes in between, if any.

With respect to the current page. The `nextSibling` to the question is a `TextNode(Whitespace)` but if I want to get the `#answers` I will use `nextElementSibling`

[image]

[image]