# How does NextSibling work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering how property [*NextSibling*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp) works in case of using method [*getElementsByClassName*()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp) ?
Here is an code example showing the problem:

```js
function Sibling() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('firstClass')[0];
    document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = 'We are on <b> ' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>';
    x = x.nextSibling;
    document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = 'After SINGLE nextSibling we are on <b> ' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>. WHY IS THAT???!!!';
    x = x.nextSibling;
    document.getElementById("out3").innerHTML = 'After DOUBLE nextSibling we are on <b> ' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>';;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
 <div class="firstClass">
 </div>
 
 <div class="secondClass">
 </div>
 
 <button onclick="Sibling()">ClickMeAndThenExplainTheResults</button>
</div>

<p id="out1"></p> 
<p id="out2"></p> 
<p id="out3"></p>
```

So, after the very first *NextSibling* I expected to get on the second element:

`<div class="secondClass">`

But for uknown reasons you need to call double *NextSibling* to move from the first element to the second one.
And as you can see after the first *NextSibling* the *TypeName* of the object is *Text*. But I don't see any text actually...

Could you please explain why we need using two *NextSibling* and what's the *Text* object is getting after using the first *NextSibling*?

Answer (score 4):

`nextSibling` gets *the next node* and not *the next node that is an element*.

Between the two div element nodes, there is a text node containing white space (spaces, tab, and new lines *are* text) and that is what you are getting.

Compare:

```
1: <div></div> <div></div>
2: <div></div><div></div>
```

See also [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).

Comment: Damn! So simple! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

As `nextSibling` returns the next Node object (even a space or a line feed),
you must want to use `nextElementSibling` instead.

See this question for details:
[Whats the difference between nextElementSibling vs nextSibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097016/whats-the-difference-between-nextelementsibling-vs-nextsibling)

And here is a working snippet:

```js
(function Sibling() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('firstClass')[0];
  document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = 'Current: <b>' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>';
  x = x.nextElementSibling;
  document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = 'Next 1  : <b>' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>';
  x = x.nextElementSibling;
  document.getElementById("out3").innerHTML = 'Next 2  : <b>' + x.className + '</b>. TypeName of the object is <i> ' + x.constructor.name + '</i>';
})()
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="firstClass">
  </div>

  <div class="secondClass">
  </div>

  <button>I do nothing</button>
</div>

<p id="out1"></p>
<p id="out2"></p>
<p id="out3"></p>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks too. The `nextElementSibling` is more useful in my case.