# Store the inner html of the sibling of the targeted element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code and I just can't make it work.
A target occurs on an element and I have to find it's next sibling or I could go to its parent and then search for the sibling's class using queryselector.

The code works perfect if I replace the ** line ** with a query selector, so the problem is with the sibling method its 100%.

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

```
/*we put on event listener for each "refsz" class*/
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("refsz");

for (var z = 0; z < elements.length; z++) {
    elements[z].addEventListener('click', callThis, false);
}

/*and when the event occurs, I select the sibling div's innerHTML and change
"success" div's innerHTML to this*/

function callThis() {

**var temp= event.target.nextSibling.innerHTML;**
document.querySelector("#success").innerHTML = temp;
}

<div class="parent">

<div> class="refsz"> I will click this </div>
<div> class="sibling"> I need the innerHTML of this sibling</div>

</div>

<div id="success"></div>
```

Comment: `var text= event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".ClassOf").innerHTML;` outside of a function doesn't make sense

Comment: Show actual code and what is `.ClassOf` since it does not match your sample html

Comment: Sorry, edited! Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: `callThis` function need `event` parameter

Comment: No, that's working fine without that parameter. The only part which is not working the sibling part :(

Comment: @makiwara please put the error text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to rather call the function `nextElementSibling` rather than `nextSibling`.

Explanation on **W3schools**:

> The nextElementSibling property returns the element immediately following the specified element, in the same tree level.
>
> The difference between this property and nextSibling, is that nextSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while nextElementSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

More [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp).

Explanation from **MDN**:

> The NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling read-only property returns the element immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list, or null if the specified element is the last one in the list.

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).

You can also read more about the differences between `nextSibling` and `nextElementSibling` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097016/whats-the-difference-between-nextelementsibling-vs-nextsibling).

---

**Other errors:**

- Your divs did not include the class attribute inside their tags
- Inside of the function `callThis()` you should call `this.nextElementSibling` instead of `this.event.nextSibling`
- you can also use `document.getElementById("success")` instead of `document.querySelector("#success")` since you know the id of the element

---

**Here is the corrected code:**

```js
/*we put on event listener for each "refsz" class*/
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("refsz");

for(var z=0; z < elements.length; z++) {
  elements[z].addEventListener('click', callThis, false);
}

/*and when the event occurs, I select the sibling div's innerHTML and change
"success" div's innerHTML to this*/

function callThis() {
  var temp= this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="refsz"> I will click this </div>
  <div class="sibling"> I need the innerHTML of this sibling</div>
</div>

<div id="success"></div>
```

Comment: Ivan you are great! This line "var temp= this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;" solved everything! Thank you very much for your help, I can't tell you how happy you made me! You are AWESOME!