# nextSibling instead of nextElementSibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This isn't exactly a problem in the code, but I cannot understand the reason behind my problem. First, please have a look at the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Head First : Javascript</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="row1">
            <p>False</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
        </div>
        <div id="row2">
            <p>False</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <p>False</p>
        </div>
        <div id="row3">
            <p>False</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>True</p>
        </div>
        <div id="row4">
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    margin:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JS:

```
function setElementColor(){
    var numberRows = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter total number of rows that you are seeing on the screen."));

    for(var i = 1; i <= numberRows; i++){
        var firstElement = document.getElementById('row' + i).firstElementChild;
        var counterElement;
        //For now, total elements in 1 row = 5
        for(var q = 1; q <= 5; q++){
            if(q == 1){
                firstElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                counterElement = firstElement.nextSibling;
            }
            else{
                counterElement.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
            counterElement = counterElement.nextElementSibling;
        }
    }
}
setElementColor();
```

Now, this might be a stupid question, but it will make sense (I believe). The code that you are seeing is correct, and works without a doubt. But, can you see that `nextSibling` property in the first `if` statement? That is what is confusing me.

Now, all paragraphs have spaces between each other, so this means that all browsers will see those spaces as `textNode` (except IE). Now, by the means of logic, there should have been a `nextElementSibling` property there, so that the code looks forward for the next Element, ignoring comments/textNodes, but I tried it, and that is not working.

Can someone give me a satisfying reasoning behind that?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226571/what-is-the-difference-between-node-nextsibling-and-childnode-nextelementsibling

Comment: what to enter in `input propmt`

Comment: @ozil, we need to enter total number of rows, in this case, 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first if, counterElement is set to the nextSibling, being the textnode

```
if
{
   counterElement = firstElement.nextSibling; //now counterElement is the textnode
}
else
{
}
counterElement = counterElement.nextElementSibling; //no matter if the counterElement is a textnode or a <p> the next element in the sibling tree is a <p>
```

But regardless of q and the if..else branch taken, immediately after the if..else block, counterElement is set to the next Element sibling, so that regardless if the starting point is the textnode or the containing paragraph, the next element will be the sibling paragraph. The code would behave the same if you would set `counterElement = firstElement` in the q == 1 block

---

As an aside, to get rid of the fixed upperbound (columns) and loose the if..else at the same time, you could also use something like

```
for(var i = 1; i <= numberRows; i++){
    var el = document.getElementById('row' + i).firstElementChild;
    var q = 1;
    while (el!=null){
        el.style.backgroundColor = q++ == 1 ? "red" : "green";
        el = el.nextElementSibling;
    }
}
```