# Plain Javascript: event.target : Get the next Sibling, & the first Child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table and have set up event listeners for each row:

```
var greyHeadings = document.querySelectorAll(".grey");

console.log(greyHeadings);

greyHeadings.forEach(function(greyHeading){
  greyHeading.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    displayDescription(e, greyHeading);
  });
});
```

The function which is called ( `displayDescription` ) is the following one:

```
function displayDescription(e, greyHeading){
  var desc = e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild;
  console.log(desc);
}
```

It does get me the correct target, but it seems that `nextSibiling.firstChild` does not work. I need to get to the next row (so, the sibling), and find the first td (so, the first Child), so i can add a `active` class to it, -in case you're wondering.

I have also created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vpzLfke/

I am a beginner, so an explanation which is a little bit more detailed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the [*forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method of the NodeList interface is not supported by a good number of browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG thanks for the info. I will look forward to a *[].slice* free time...

Answer (score 15):

You will have to use `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling`, since `nextElementSibling` always returns an HTML Element. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226571/what-is-the-difference-between-node-nextsibling-and-childnode-nextelementsibling)

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Perfect ! It is a very good question and I couldnt find a better solution. thanks for this