# How to hide previous div in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 4 div. When I click on one of the divs the green shown will expand. Then I click on another diva and a green background with subtitles will also be shown. I mean, I want only one div to be expanded. For example, if I click the 3 div it expands me the content of the 3 diva. Then I click the 2 div and it expands me the content of the 2 diva and automatically hides the content of the previous div that was expanded. I hope that everone understand what I want to do.

```js
<script>

function showHide(obj)
{

var nextObj=obj.nextSibling;
while(!nextObj.tagName) nextObj=nextObj.nextSibling;
nextObj.style.display = nextObj.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none';
}

</script>
```

```css
.iptv{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
background-color:blue;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:white;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.drop{
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button1</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button2</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button3</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button4</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You code doesn't work.

Comment: I my notepade work.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`??

Comment: Why you're doing it vanilla?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

1. The `div`s weren't "closed"
2. It's not `obj.nextSibling`, but `obj.nextElementSibling` (there's a difference: [What is the difference between node.nextSibling and ChildNode.nextElementSibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226571/what-is-the-difference-between-node-nextsibling-and-childnode-nextelementsibling))

After correcting these errors and adding the code for closing the other `div`s, the snippet works:

```js
function showHide(obj) {
  const nextObj = obj.nextElementSibling;
  const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('.drop')
  dropDowns.forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = 'none'
  })
  nextObj.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
.iptv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.drop {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="down">
  <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button1</div>
  <div class="drop" style="display:none">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="About">About</a>
    <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="down">
  <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button2</div>
  <div class="drop" style="display:none">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="About">About</a>
    <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="down">
  <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button3</div>
  <div class="drop" style="display:none">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="About">About</a>
    <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="down">
  <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button4</div>
  <div class="drop" style="display:none">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="About">About</a>
    <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see now, I really gratefull that you help me.

Comment: @MateuszWojno happy days, buddy! :D