# Express item.parentElement.remove() in a way that is supported by IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom-events

From what I understand, the

```
remove()
```

function is not supported in IE. I have a JS function that creates a div and appends it to an existing list.The div contains another div styled as a button (this is the 'item' in the title, that's what I called it when I got it from HTML), which, on click, removes its parentNode (and consequently itself) from the DOM (by means of `remove()`), though it still 'exists' in that JavaScript can read it's data and stuff. I need a way to remove it from the DOM, as well as all of it's child elements. Setting it's innerHTML equal to nothing will not work, nor will setting it's display to none. Any idea how to do this in a way compatible with IE?

Any help appreciated, please no jQuery or other frameworks.

Comment: MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you would use `.remove()`, you can always just use `.removeChild()` instead with slightly different code around it.

So, if you wanted to do to remove the parent of a given node:

```
item.parentElement.remove();
```

Then, you can instead do this:

```
var p = item.parentNode;
p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
```

---

If you want to put this in a utility function, you can do this:

```
function removeNode(node) {
    node.parentNode.removechild(node);
}
```

And, in your case, instead of `item.parentElement.remove()` you would call it like this:

```
removeNode(item.parentNode);
```

Note, I'm using `parentNode` instead of `parentElement` since you appear to want IE compatibility with older versions of IE.  `parentNode` and `parentElement` are not exactly the same, but it's very rare where `parentNode` would be different than `parentElement` (in fact, I can't think of a case in a normal DOM where it wouldn't be appropriate to use `parentNode`).  See [Difference between DOM parentNode and parentElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement) for a discussion of the differences.

Comment: @Leshy - Did this answer solve your issue? If so, please mark as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.   If your issue has not yet been solved, then please explain what else you are confused about.