# JavaScript parent.removeChild(child) not working

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble using parent.removeChild(). I think I am using the correct syntax. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
var parent = document.body
var child = document.getElementById("clueDiv")
parent.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: If that's not working, probably is because "clueDiv" is not a direct child of "document.body"

Answer (score 2):

If that does not work, probably `child` is not child of `document.body`.

Try with:

```
child.parentElement.removeChild(child)
```

Or, as @PaulS. said:

```
child.parentNode.removeChild(child)
```

Comment: Why `.parentElement` and not `.parentNode`?

Comment: Wow, I wrote the same at the same time in the comments of the question. Upvote ;)

Comment: @PaulS. I've never seen a case when they are not the same ;) Anyway, I guess `parentNode` probably does work in more cases.

Comment: BTW, a link for the curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement

Comment: @zvone Most often you'd encounter differences when you reach non-Element nodes such as a _#document-fragment_ or _#document_ at the top of the DOM tree, where `.parentElement` becomes `null` but you could still append and remove child nodes to these objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

```
var child = document.getElementById("clueDiv");
child.remove();
```

It's not supported in Internet Explorer, but you can use a polyfill:

```
if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        if (this.parentNode) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I wanted to warn this was defined in a draft. But wow, DOM4 is already a recommendation!