# How to add class to parent in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Not jQuery as I would simply do `$("this").parent().addClass("active");` but in pure **javascript**. This is because i don't want to mix up Javascript and jQuery on the following code:

```
var clickedPath = this.getElement(); 
clickedPath.classList.add("active"); 
var classes = clickedPath.getAttribute('class').match(/\d+/g) || []; 
buttons.forEach(function(btn) { 
    var method = classes.indexOf(btn.getAttribute('data-date')) > -1 ? 'add' : 'remove'; 
    btn.classList[method]('active');
    //btn.parent().addClass("active");
});
```

> **UPDATE**

This is the HTML starting case before the classes are added:

```
<ul>
  <li>1500</li>
  <li>1400
      <ul>
        <li>1401</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

We have 2 situations:

- 1500 is single and doesn't have a child
- 1400 has a child 1401

If I am adding the class `active` to 1500, it's fine and I can use the code provided in the answer:

```
btn.parentNode.classList[method]('active');
```

But If I add the class to 1401, also 1400 should have it, so the followings are the two cases:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">1500</li>
  <li>1400
      <ul>
        <li>1401</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul>
  <li>1500</li>
  <li class="active">1400
      <ul>
        <li class="active">1401</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you would be looking for `btn.parentNode` instead of `btn.parent()` if I am reading your code right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You mention " i don't want to mix up js and jQuery on the following code" but you are actually mixing vanilla DOM APIs with jQuery methods. `.parent` and `.addClass` are jQuery functions. You can code:

```
btn.parentNode.classList.add("active");
```

Comment: this is providing the class to all parents tho

Comment: `.parentNode` returns just one DOM element.

Comment: i want to show it to you, how can we go to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128549/discussion-between-rob-m-and-undefined).

Answer (score 6):

Also consider `parentElement` as an alternative to `parentNode`:

```
btn.parentElement.classList.add("active");
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: parentNode vs parentElement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement

Answer (score 1):

You need .parentNode on the element.

Something like this.

```
var clickedPath = this.getElement();
clickedPath.classList.add("active");
var classes = clickedPath.getAttribute('class').match(/\d+/g) || [];
buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  var method = classes.indexOf(btn.getAttribute('data-date')) > -1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
  btn.classList[method]('active');
  btn.parentNode.classList.add("active");
});
```