# Nodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I'm new to nodes and I'm just trying to wrap my head around them. For whatever reason this isn't working, I've tried anything i could find and no luck.

this is what I'm trying to do "Using the JavaScript function getElementById(), access the text of mySpecialParagraph using nodeValue. Create a paragraph element using createElement() and, using createTextNode(), append a string to this new element that reads “ See: I can use JavaScript”.
Using insertBefore(), insert this text before mySpecialParagraph."

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  var msp = document.getElementById("mySpecialParagraph");
  var parent = msp.parent();

  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(" See: I can use JavaScript");
  para.appendChild(textNode);
  parent.insertBefore(para, msp);
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, I've put it through a validator and nothing comes up on the web page

Comment: Can you please add this to a jsfiddle or something similar and post the link? also, are you trying to use jQuery? Also, please elaborate your question a bit so that we know exactly what you are trying to accomplish (your intention)

Comment: `var parent = msp.parent();` should, I think, be`var parent = msp.parentNode;` if that's so, however, you should be getting errors reported in the console.

Comment: Please read [ask], and look into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7rmvadgLUT theres the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parent()` does not exist in plain JS. It should be `.parentElement` or `.parentNode`. The latter is the most popular I think. The difference between the two is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement).

```js
var msp = document.getElementById("mySpecialParagraph");
var parent = msp.parentNode;

var para = document.createElement("p");
var textNode = document.createTextNode(" See: I can use JavaScript");
para.appendChild(textNode);
parent.insertBefore(para, msp);
```

```html
<p id="mySpecialParagraph"></p>
```

Comment: You can see it working right here, so it does work. Something else must be wrong in your code. Probably your HTML.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know you could run it. I just made a jsfiddle could you have a look? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7rmvadgLUT

Comment: `.parentNode` does not need parentheses `()`. It's not a function. It's a value.