# How to check if two DOM nodes are siblings without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

How can you check if two DOM nodes are siblings without jquery?

```
<div>
   <a></a>
   <b></b>
   <c>
       <d></d>
   </c>
</div>
```

`a` and `c` are siblings but `a` and `d` are not.
`a` and `a` are not siblings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check their `.parentElement` property.

```
let isSibling = el1 !== el2 && el1.parentElement === el2.parentElement;
```

Comment: it's `parentNode`?

Answer (score 2):

Why not check `parentNode` (or `parentElement`) property?

```
function areSiblings(a, b) {
  return a!=b && a.parentNode == b.parentNode; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`.parentElement` or `.parentNode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement) to determine if they share the same parent.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a');
var b = document.querySelector('b');
var c = document.querySelector('c');
var d = document.querySelector('d');


function areSiblings(x, y) {
  return x !== y && x.parentElement === y.parentElement;
}

function areSiblings2(x, y) {
  return x !== y && x.parentNode === y.parentNode;
}

console.log(areSiblings(a, b)); // true
console.log(areSiblings(a, c)); // true
console.log(areSiblings(a, d)); // false

console.log(areSiblings2(a, b)); // true
console.log(areSiblings2(a, c)); // true
console.log(areSiblings2(a, d)); // false
```

```html
<div>
   <a></a>
   <b></b>
   <c>
       <d></d>
   </c>
</div>
```