# JS get parent id of a child from within a child

Tags: javascript

I have these 3 divs

Is there a way to get the id `parent` when you click on that child of child, and if yes, how?

```js
function getParentId(el) {
  //get the id "parent"
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-of-child" onClick="getParentId(this)">
      <!-- some code here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean, like `el.parentElement`?

Comment: Hey @EvanKnowles, i mean the el.parent.of.parent cause my div is a child of a child of a parent...o god this is dizzy stuff :(

Comment: Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement

Comment: - To get ID attribute:     el.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id')

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq or just el.parentElement.parentElement.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```js
function getParentId(el){
   var p = el.parentNode.parentNode;
   console.log(p.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-of-child" onClick="getParentId(this)">
        <!-- some code here -->
        Click
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mamun! It works now :D thank you thank you thank you <3

Comment: @emma, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `el.parentElement` inside the click function:

```js
function getParentId(el){
   var id = el.parentElement.parentElement.id;
   console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-of-child" onClick="getParentId(this)">
        click
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @AnkitAngarwal, it works now, i used another answer already but thank you so so so much for taking time to answer! <3

Comment: @emma glad to help