# Argument of type '(Node & ParentNode) | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'

Tags: typescript, dom, typescript-typings

I try to pass a `parentNode` of a node to my `getStyleComputedProperty` function.

But got an error:

> Argument of type '(Node & ParentNode) | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

Code here:

```js
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];
type Property = NonFunctionPropertyNames<CSSStyleDeclaration>;
export const getStyleComputedProperty = (ele: Element, property: Property): string => {
  const css = window.getComputedStyle(ele, null);
  return css[property];
};

const div = document.createElement('div')
getStyleComputedProperty(div.parentNode, 'position') // tsc throw error
```

I know I can use type cast like this `div.parentNode as Element` to pass the TSC type check. But I wonder how can I make the type correct without the type cast.

Here is [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwGIFcEGNgEtEAUBOck+oMAhgLYQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN5QDaA0lFgigBrCCDgAzKPQC6ALim9pUCAA9gEBABNqUasHwCA5lAD8UPvIQQAbhHxQAvlxFjJMgNwAoUJCgEidqCssIioGNh4hMSklDS0AMIAysmgADYQACIQ6Klk+GQRCIxeqmBwJFDoiHpQhhDAiWkQ8XAUYCjqmv7RIMEAFBDp8gCi6VQIwAA0UGBRgSDy3fMAlPJ6BgjGLMzsnlCV1cCV1DpsAO4CmnBnAHR1wC1tHRCajSDpA+nTCCipqctefb4eoofCCdAnLizAIkEDSLwOLyeKoIGqaLDWYJXdAocbAG7oYEFCCjCB4voAcnR1gpy089ze6Ue7U6S1hfWpNzAeQ0wHgmgg0wpZWoWEKtKAA)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `parentElement` instead of `parentNode`:

```js
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];
type Property = NonFunctionPropertyNames<CSSStyleDeclaration>;
export const getStyleComputedProperty = (ele: Element, property: Property): string => {
  const css = window.getComputedStyle(ele, null);
  return css[property];
};

const div = document.createElement('div')
if (div.parentElement) {
  getStyleComputedProperty(div.parentElement, 'position')
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement) you can find the difference between those two

You are right, using type casting `as` should be the last resort

Comment: It seems the behaviours of parentNode and parentElement are not the same. So I worry it will break for runtime.