# querySelector child to parent

Tags: javascript

Nowadays I am working on an application. I been struggling for a while how I should select a parent of a child.

What I trying to do is
Click on child(card) and do something with a parent(cell).

Is there a way how I could querySelector the parent e.g.

`const selectedParentFromChild = document.querySelector(".child .parent")`

**Solution:**

For those which were struggled as well. You can use **parentElement** like @Phix has mentioned down below in the comments.

Comment: Please provide sample html as per [mre]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

Comment: Use [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Comment: It is just a simple question, because I want to select a parent of a child by using querySelector. Is that possible @charlietfl

Comment: Not in one selector no. The two methods already provided will help you. You need to query  the child first then query the parent from that element

Comment: Thanks @Phix this is working like a charm! And is even compatible in multiple browsers. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
let child = document.querySelector(".child");
let parent = child.parentNode;
```

and you can't get the parent of a child via css only, there is currently no such selector see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: `.child` is not an id, but a class. The same with `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` should work. There is also a typo, the last char should be `;`instead of `,`.

Comment: No problem, the idea was right, just some small corrections. Also, this may be of interest here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685780/4477659

Comment: Which is better to use parentNode or parentElement I been searching on the caniuse.com website and there I saw that the parentNode is more compatible then the parentElement, but the parentNode has more errors.

Comment: @ValdemarVreeman for the most cases there are the same, see here for differences
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement-in-javascript/

Comment: @ValdemarVreeman can you please check my answer, if it is for you, thanks

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 ways to do that:

1. you can use the `Element.parentElement`, it's return the parent element.
2. you can use `Element.closest()`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

> The `closest()` method of the Element interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector.

```js
const child = document.querySelector(".child");
const parentMatched = child.closest(".parent-matched");
```